# Unable to start Cassandra, getting Java error "Invalid decorator", "Invalid -Xlog option"

Tags: cassandra

I'm getting below error while trying to start cassandra services on the ubuntu platform.

```
$ /u01/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0/bin/cassandra
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[0.001s][error][logging] Invalid decorator 'cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0/gc.log'.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc=info,heap*=trace,age*=debug,safepoint=info,promotion*=trace:file=/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0/gc.log:time,uptime,pid,tid,level:filecount=10,filesize=10485760', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

$ python --version
Python 3.8.10

$ /u01/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.11/bin/cassandra -v
4.0.11

$ grep -a5 'VM_OPTS -Xlog' cassandra-env.sh 
if [ $JAVA_VERSION -ge 11 ] ; then
    echo "$JVM_OPTS" | grep -qe "-[X]log:gc"
    if [ "$?" = "1" ] ; then # [X] to prevent ccm from replacing this line
        mkdir -p ${CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR}
        JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xlog:gc*=info,heap*=trace,age*=debug,safepoint=info,promotion*=trace:file=${CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR}/gc.log:time,uptime,pid,tid,level:filecount=10,filesize=10485760"
    fi
else
    echo "$JVM_OPTS" | grep -qe "-[X]loggc"
    if [ "$?" = "1" ] ; then # [X] to prevent ccm from replacing this line
        mkdir -p ${CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR}
        JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xloggc:${CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR}/gc.log"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

That's coming from the `<your install path>/conf/jvm11-server.options` file in your installation.

Check the `system.log` (& `debug.log`) for more details.

---

You're also mixing different install location as I can see you're using 2 different paths:

1. `/u01/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0/bin/cassandra` and
2. `/u01/cassandra/apache-cassandra-4.0.11/bin/cassandra`

so, check on that too.

Comment: I successfully initiated the Cassandra services by making a minor modification in the `cassandra-env.sh` file. The adjustment involved updating the section from:


`if [ "x$CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR" = "x" ] ; then
    CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR="/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0"
fi`

to:

`if [ "x$CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR" = "x" ] ; then
    CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR="$CASSANDRA_HOME/logs"
fi`

Comment: After implementing this modification, or reverting CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR to its default value, the functionality is restored and operational without any issues.

However I would like to know why it did not allow me to modify the configuration to use a custom log location for cassandra.

Comment: as long as you've set it as `export CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR="/your/log/location" at `cassandra-env.sh` file, it should allow you to speicfy a custom logging location. You don't have to touch any other (e.g. _if_ block or any other) code lines on that file to make it work.

Comment: as soon as I update the cassandra-env.sh file to provide custom location for CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR, and try starting the Cassandra service, it fails again with below  error.

`$  ../bin/cassandra 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[0.001s][error][logging] Invalid decorator 'cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0/gc.log'.`

Comment: ```Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*=info,heap*=trace,age*=debug,safepoint=info,promotion*=trace:file=/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_delphix_apache_stg_n_0/gc.log:time,uptime,pid,tid,level:filecount=10,filesize=10485760', see error log for details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.```

Comment: how exactly did you update the script and what did you add there? `/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_delphix_apache_stg_n_0/gc.log` doesn't look like a valid file path to me. What if you did a `ls -l` on that path and also check if the process running the C* has full access to those directories?

Comment: The specified path, `/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_delphix_apache_stg_n_0`, is indeed a valid directory, and the process running Cassandra has the necessary permissions to read and write in this folder.

Comment: Upon validation, I found that updating the CASSANDRA_LOG_DIRECTORY to `/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc_cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_delphix_apache_stg_n_0` allows the services to start without encountering any issues.

Comment: It appears that the issue arises when the CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR is set to `/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_delphix_apache_stg_n_0`. The problem lies in how the Cassandra service interprets the cassandra-env.sh script to evaluate the value of `CASSANDRA_LOG_DIR`. Specifically, the folder `sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8` seems to be causing an issue during Cassandra startup.

Comment: The error message indicates an invalid decorator, specifically mentioning the problematic folder in the path, and it points to issues with the -Xlog options during the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) startup. The error log suggests that the combination of directory structure and log options is causing problems with the JVM initialization.

Comment: To resolve this issue, I have successfully tested an alternative log directory path (`/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc_cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0`) that allows Cassandra to start without encountering errors.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, there is an invalid "decorator" in your configuration.

The issue is that you have specified an invalid path to the `gc.log` in:

```
-Xlog:gc=info,heap*=trace,age*=debug,safepoint=info,promotion*=trace:file=/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0/gc.log:time,uptime,pid,tid,level:filecount=10,filesize=10485760
```

Specifically:

```
file=/home/dlpx/toolkit/dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host/plugin/sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8/.dlpx/apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0/gc.log
```

Here's a reformatted version to make it easier to spot the problem:

```
file=
  /home
    /dlpx
      /toolkit
        /dlpx_COMMON_ab6c1fa92de3_c1b768c7d228_host
          /plugin
            /sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8
              /.dlpx
                /apache-cassandra-4.0.11_dlpx_apache_stg_n_0
                  /gc.log
```

Hopefully you could see that the name of one of the subdirectories contains a colon (`:`):

```
    sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8
```

The JVM options are separated by colons (`:`). Since the name of the subdirectory contains a colon, the parser incorrectly thinks that `cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8` in `sc:cassandra_1ebd9629-9754-4edc-915e-dd29cdcc3aa8` is another JVM option but doesn't recognise it leading to the `Invalid decorator` error.

If you set the path to the `gc.log` correctly, you should be able to start Cassandra. Cheers!